# Select stored procedure variables

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures

Is there a way to select the variables a stored procedure will receive?

For example I have a table of clients, my primary key is an autonumeric long.

My stored procedure is called `SelectClientByKey` and would be something like

```
select * 
from clients 
where clientId = @clientid
```

I have many other stored procedures, and I would like to make a query that gets the variables that the stored procedure has and it's data types.

Something like:

```
Select Variable, Type 
From StoredProcedure 
Where StoredProcedure.Name = 'SelectClientByKey'
```

The results should be

```
@clientId bigInt
```

I'm not sure if that's possible, any advice?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly stolen from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1669/generate-a-parameter-list-for-all-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-functions/). If you run it, it will given you a list of all stored procedures and their parameters as well as some useful extended information.

```
SELECT
   SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema], 
   SO.name AS [ObjectName],
   SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType (UDF/SP)],
   P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID],
   P.name AS [ParameterName],
   TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType],
   P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
   P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P 
   ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.OBJECT_ID IN (
   SELECT OBJECT_ID 
   FROM sys.objects
   WHERE TYPE IN ('P','FN')
)
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can use below SQL query to get stored procedure, parameter list and its datatype:

```
SELECT 
    o.name as StoredProcedure, p.name as Parameter, t.name as DataType
FROM 
    sys.all_objects o
JOIN
    sys.parameters p ON p.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN
    sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id
WHERE 
    o.name = 'SelectClientByKey'    -- Your stored procedure name
```